# Trying to get the sum of pairs that equal to a prime number

Tags: java

I am trying to get four input from the user and try to find pairs that equal to a prime number just by using user defined methods. i din reach the prime step yet. But before that i ran into a problem. So jus to check the sum I TRIED printing it out in the method called sumPair6 but it prints zero, so the sum is returning 0 for everything. don't know what mistake am i doing. I got rid of the initial 0 too but still doesn't not work

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class prime
{
    public static int  num1 = 0,  num2 = 0,  num3 = 0,  num4 = 0, sum1= 0,sum2,sum3,sum4,sum5,sum6,val1,stop;  
    public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String args[])
    {  
        input();
        sumPair1(num1, num2, sum1);
        sumPair2(num1, num3, sum2);
        sumPair3(num1, num4, sum3);
        sumPair4(num2, num3, sum4);
        sumPair5(num2, num4, sum5);
        sumPair6(num3, num4, sum6);
       // Prime(sum1,sum2,sum3,sum4,sum5,sum6,val1,stop);
    }        
    public static void input ()
    {      
        System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");        
        num1 = input.nextInt(); 
        if(num1==0 || num1 < 0)
            while(num1==0 || num1 < 0)
            {
                System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
                num1 = input.nextInt();
            }            
        if(num1 > 0)

            System.out.println("Thank you."); 

        System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");        
        num2 = input.nextInt(); 
        if(num2==0 || num2 < 0)
            while(num2 == 0 || num2 < 0)
            {
                System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
                num2 = input.nextInt();
            }            
        if(num2 > 0)

            System.out.println("Thank you.");                                

        System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");        
        num3 = input.nextInt(); 
        while(num3 ==0 || num3 < 0)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
            num3 = input.nextInt();
        }     
        if(num3 > 0)

            System.out.println("Thank you.");                                

        System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");        
        num4 = input.nextInt(); 
        if(num4==0 || num4 < 0)
            while(num4 == 0 || num4 < 0)
            {
                System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
                num4 = input.nextInt();
            }
        if(num4 > 0)

            System.out.println("Thank you.");                                

    } 
    public static int sumPair1(int num1, int num2, int sum1)
     {
        sum1 = num1 + num2;
        return sum1;
    }

    public static int sumPair2(int num1,int num3,int sum2)
      {       
        sum2 = num1 + num3;
         System.out.println(sum1);
        return sum2;
    }

    public static int sumPair3(int num1, int num4,int sum3)
    {  
        sum3 = num1 + num4;
        return sum3;
    }

    public static int sumPair4(int num2, int num3,int sum4)
    {  
        sum4 = num2 + num3;
        return sum4;
    }

    public static int sumPair5(int num2,int num4,int sum5)
    {  
        sum5 = num2 + num4;
        return sum5;
    }

    public static int sumPair6(int num3, int num4,int sum6)
    { 
        sum6 = num3 + num4;  
        System.out.println(sum1);
        return sum6;        
    }
}
```

Comment: You really should look into Array, ArrayList, Map etc :) (for the data storage)

Comment: So you want me to get rid of all the sumpair user defined methods?? @Mikenno

Comment: added an answer, should work like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that you are printing `sum1` which is NOT set at the time you are printing meaing it retuns the 0 it was default valued to, a quick fix is priting the one you summed in the method, but another fix is to do as i will propose here

To fix this code do something like

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    input();
    sum1 = sumPair(num1, num2);
    sum2 = sumPair(num1, num3);
    sum3 = sumPair(num1, num4);
    sum4 = sumPair(num2, num3);
    sum5 = sumPair(num2, num4);
    sum6 = sumPair(num3, num4);
    // Prime(sum1,sum2,sum3,sum4,sum5,sum6,val1,stop);
}
```

and then

```
public static int sumPair(int num1, int num2) { // returns a sum of 2 numers
    return num1 + num2;
}
```

This is because you are always adding 2 integers, so no need for more than 1 function for it.

**Extra**

Rewritten most the class to make it is easier to read and use

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Prime {

    public static List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(); // a list of integers that was accepted, can be acced in the order they were added

    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int inputs = 4; // inputs wanted
        input(inputs); // gives the method the inputs wanted
        for(int i = 0; i < inputs; i++){ // for every entry in the list (notice that we add to the list in the input()
            for(int j = 0+i; j < inputs; j++) // again for every element (to sum all numbers), notice +i to prevent duplicates
            {
                if(i != j) // if the numbers aren't the same entry
                    // print the number returned from the sum function
                    System.out.println("sum of " + numbers.get(i)+ " and " + numbers.get(j) + ": " + sumPair(numbers.get(i), numbers.get(j)));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void input(int inputNumbers) {

        while(numbers.size() < inputNumbers){ // while there is more inputs needed
            System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
            int num = input.nextInt();
            if(num > 0) // if the input is valid
                numbers.add(num);
            else // if the input is not valid
                while (num <= 0) { // while the input is not valid
                    System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
                    num = input.nextInt(); // get the next int if it wasn't valid
                    if(num > 0) { // if the input gets valid
                        numbers.add(num);
                    }
                }
            System.out.println("Thank you.");
        }
    }

    public static int sumPair(int num1, int num2) { // sums 2 integers given to the method and returns the sum
        return num1 + num2;
    }
}
```

Now this isn't a perfect class, it is just simplified some, but it should show you how to search for a range, and how that a function can be re-used, if you have questions ask in the comments below

for input 1,2,3,4 this will print

> sum of 1 and 2: 3
>
> sum of 1 and 3: 4
>
> sum of 1 and 4: 5
>
> sum of 2 and 3: 5
>
> sum of 2 and 4: 6
>
> sum of 3 and 4: 7

Comment: So if i don't use a variable for num1 + num2 how will i use that in my next method

Comment: @rancer as i have shown here it simply expects an integer, it doesn't matter where the integer is from (adding some more context soon)

Comment: @rancer added some more to the answer

Comment: `System.out.println("sum of " + numbers.get(i)+ " and " + numbers.get(j) + ": " + sumPair(numbers.get(i), numbers.get(j)));` I dont understand this step and it does not compile too. @Mikenno

Comment: @rancer just tried to copy and run it again, it definetly works, you sure have *import java.util.ArrayList;*  and *import java.util.List;* in the imports ? as for the question, i'll try and clarify it some.

And it is *1. System.out.println() prints the thing in it*, *2. using "a" + "b" meand that it is making a string of ab (it's trying to add them before printing it*, *3. numbers.get(i) is trying to acces the List "numbers" and then gain the element at i* , *4. sumPair(int arg1, int arg2) takes 2 ints (here from the list) and then sums and returns the summed value*

Comment: So when I compile it shows an error saying variable can't be found at `numbers.get(i)`

Comment: @rancer first, try and clean and build (also notice the class is Prime with a capital P, opposed to the prime as in the question), after that if it still isn't working, try and explain the steps you take to run the code, (remember to mention the IDE you are using and the exact error)

Comment: so I got of my entire code and started a new one. I imported all those lines and then copied the following code, and it shows an error as mentioned above. I am using BlueJ

Comment: right ... must be something BlueJ fails to do proberly then ... (tested it in IntelliJ, Netbeans, and Eclipse) i'm 100% sure this code compiles and runs

Comment: nope, my fault, so it worked when i changed the prime. so it compiles but it never runs. When i try to run it says error calling method call: cannot find symbol-variable prime

Comment: @rancer sounds like you still dind't proberly import it, BlueJ proberly is still using the non capital prime, so i would suggest either move or delete the project file and then reimport it (or just create a new Java class if BlueJ can do that ?) and make sure that the class is called "Prime" and then just add in the code and it should compile and run (notice i fixed a minor error when an input was non valid so copy the code again)

Comment: Great thank you so much sir. So i do not want the duplicate sum and thats i called a separate method in that code. so i do i get rid of the duplicate pairs

Comment: @rancer yes as i showed here by iterating the list twice and just not priting the ones that are dublicates it only sums the non duplicate ones as the code is now, notice the *if* before the print statement as it states if they are refering the same entry, do nothing (remember to mark as accepted and upvote if it answered the question)

Comment: so by duplicate i mean 1 and 2 = 3; And 2 and 1 also 3; I think the if statements only get rid of same values like 1 and 1

Comment: @rancer fixed it, now the 2nd loop jumps over the i's used and thus there can't be duplicates

Comment: For that for loop that was added , it brings up an error, illegal start of a statement

Comment: @rancer ye typo, fixed that as well :) (just remove the /

Comment: @rancer no problem, glad it was helpfull :)

Answer (score 0):

the scope of the variables are only within a particular method. within input(), you take user inputs and assign them to your variables but as soon as the execution thread comes out of input, your variables num1, num2 etc. have same pre-defined values (all 0).

you can re-design your code in many ways. one simple way is to call sumpair method from within input() method, so you will need only one sumpair method, which can take different num values.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: @Jayz that is not the issue, notice as i mentioned in my answer he is printing sum1 and not the one he sum'ed